# Get the row with a NULL column from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, having, sql-null

How do I get the row which has a `null` value in `address_1` from below query.

```
SELECT id, address_1, address_2, address_3 FROM table GROUP BY address_2, address_3 HAVING COUNT(id) > 1;
```

There is only one row which has a `null` value in `address_1` in all groupings.

```
id    address_1    address_2    address_3
-----------------------------------
1    7 Orange     High County  CA 10020
2                 High County  CA 10020
3    20 Orange    High County  CA 10020
4                 True Avenue  VA 24019
5    100 Apple    True Avenue  VA 24019
6    123 Apple    True Avenue  VA 24019
7                 Long Island  NY 10000
...
```

I would like to get the id of the row 2 and 4 (to update or delete it accordingly).

Comment: Please include the starting data as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just updated table with more data.

Comment: How is this query working at all if you're selecting non-aggregated columns?

Comment: Also, could you clarify what your desired outcome is? Do you want to select all rows where address_1 is null, but only if they belong to groups of size >=1, grouped by address_2, address_3? Or something else?

Comment: I would like to get id=2 and id=4 only. id=7 will not be included in the `GORUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(id) > 1` grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN address_1 IS NULL THEN id END) id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY address_2, address_3
HAVING COUNT(address_1) > 0 AND COUNT(address_1) < COUNT(*);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65fbfcc85f7db7e055d9ca0c1607d402).

Comment: Yes! Conditional aggregation solves the problem"

Answer (score 1):

To find such `id` values, you may use:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE address_1 IS NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.address_2 = t1.address_2 AND
                    t2.address_3 = t1.address_3 AND
                    t2.id <> t1.id AND
                    t2.id IS NOT NULL);
```

### Demo

Comment: How do I not make it to exclude id=7?  id=7 will not be included in the `GORUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(id) > 1` grouping.

Comment: @tarako Sure, check the updated answer above.

Comment: It works but I was looking something like forpas's answer using group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, address_1, address_2, address_3 
FROM table 
WHERE address_1 IS NULL 
group by address_2,address_3;
```

if There is only one row that has a null value in `address_1` in each group then there is no need to group by.

is that what you need? or am I didn't understand you?

Comment: It will not work when the row contains null address_1 does not come first in its grouping.

Comment: I edited my answer check it if that is what you mean?

Comment: I would like to exclude data like id=7 from the result by using the GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 grouping.